# Java getting an input from a joystick like an xbox conroler without using an external api

Tags: java, input, joystick

This might just be me not finding it anywhere but how would I go about getting a joystick input from something like an xbox controller without using any external apis to help me. Most of what I found using an api called JInput.

Comment: JInput is the closest thing to a standard Java API for joystick input.

Answer (score 2):

You will pretty much have to use an API - the controller gives input to the operating system, and getting that system data requires lower level access than normal Java permits.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time api is nothing but a well written java library to be used for client java code.Saying all that, you can still write that api if you want so, but that would be a lot more work, not to mention the quality of the code would be. I would advise you to go with whatever api you find and write the encapsulation code

Comment: Thank you for this. I will still wait for more responses to see if anyone can help out with the original question but I'll experiment around with the JInput api because it's probably my best option.